# Is it possible to specialize variadic eponymous templates?

Tags: d

I want to extend [min](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_comparison.html#.min) so that it also works with my vector types.

For example `min` for two vectors should return a new vector that is composed of the lowest values of the two vectors.

```
min(Vec2(5,10), Vec2(-1, 15)) == Vec2(-1, 10)
```

```d
auto min(Vec...)(in Vec v){
    static import std.algorithm.comparison;
    return componentMap!(std.algorithm.comparison.min)(v);
}
auto max(Vec...)(in Vec v){
    static import std.algorithm.comparison;
    return componentMap!(std.algorithm.comparison.max)(v);
}
```

It seems that I can not extend `min`. If the two `min`'s are in the same scope then D will just choose `std.algorithm.comparison.min` and it will fail to compile. Is it possible to specialize the `min` template so that if D finds a `min` template that only contains vectors it will call the correct min template?

Comment: What error are you seeing? The above `min` signature doesn't conflict with `std.algorithm.min` for me.

Comment: Oh, weird. Its actually overriding std.algorithm.min for me ... that's not what I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std.algorithm.min` doesn't have any template contraints (at least not any that
are useful here), so it will be difficult to override if it is visible in the
current scope. However, if you haven't imported `min`, you can write a wrapper
like so:

```
enum isVector(T) = is(T == Vec2);

auto min(T...)(T args) {
    static import std.algorithm.comparison;

    static if (allSatisfy!(isVector, T))
            // return vector min
    else
        return std.algorithm.comparison.min(args);
}
```

The weird part is that the above actually works for me if I 
`import std.algorithm.comparison;`
but not if I
`import std.algorithm.comparison : min;`, which may be a bug.

However, I think your `min` departs far enough from normal `min` behavior (rather than returning one of the elements, it returns some combination thereof) that it may make sense to just give it a different name.